# Retrieving Specific value data from FireBase (Android) in listview

Tags: java, android, performance, listview, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I want to retrieve all that data whose blood group have B+ value]

```
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseRef = mFirebaseInstance.getReferenceFromUrl("https://c7d86.firebaseio.com");


mFirebaseRef.child("bloodgroup").equalTo("B+").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getUpdate(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getUpdate(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
```

So please help me because I am a new learner for firebase and have to know how to write a query in this.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: m getting all data which i enter in it. i want only "B+" bloodgroup data

Comment: it show me all data but i want only data whose having bloodgrp "B+"

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries evaluate the children under the node where you execute the query. So in your case when you use `mFirebaseRef.child("bloodgroup")` it will look for a `/bloodgroup` and then query the children under that. Since there is no `/bloodgroup`, there are no results.

The correct code:

```
mFirebaseRef = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();
DatabaseReference queryLocation = mFirebaseRef.child("the key under bloodfinder-c7d86 in the screenshot");
Query query = queryLocation.orderByChild("bloodgroup").equalTo("B+");

query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
```

Note that I had to do some guesses, because you shared a picture of the JSON. For future questions, share the JSON as text. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: its not working its display all record which is in database

Comment: That seems quite unlikely. Can you edit your question to share the updated minimum code that reproduces the issue?